# Where can I travel to receive a COVID vaccine as a tourist?

Tags: covid-19, medical-tourism

According to a [recent FT article](https://archive.is/bk4L3):

> Doses of the coronavirus vaccine developed by AstraZeneca and the University of Oxford could be available for purchase in India as soon as March, according to one manufacturer, in the first sign that the sought-after jab will make its way on to the private market.
> Once the job is approved for use, Serum will initially supply the Indian government but then expects to sell 20m-30m doses to private facilities, according to Adar Poonawalla, chief executive.

But that's going to be in March at the earliest. Are there locations where one can travel to receive the vaccine even sooner? The requirements are:

1. The country in question must be open to tourism or at least medical tourism
2. Any tourist should be able to obtain the COVID vaccine or at least any tourist over a certain age
3. Its okay if the vaccine is still in the trial phase, as long as tourists are accepted into the trial
4. Its okay if you have to pay to get the shot

NB: I am aware that traveling can be a risky activity during the pandemic, but for some people the chance to get vaccinated sooner could make the trip worth it. As an example, you might be a doctor or a nurse in [a country](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20201207-swiss-stake-slower-more-cautious-covid-vaccine-path) which won't receive the vaccine for a long time.

Comment: Are you above 65 years old? an obese person? have an autoimmune disease?

Comment: I am asking because Saudi Arabia will start giving the shots in a few days for these groups. Also, how are these _motivations_? I believe all countries are scheduling the shots based on a specific _criteria_.

Comment: (Saudi arabia isn't open to any tourist)

Comment: As number of vaccine shots are currently scarce I don't think there's any country which would give them to tourists.

Comment: I think you should add “the tourist should be able to book a vaccination prior to travel” to your list of requirements, to avoid the risk of finding out on arrival that there are no supplies/vaccination appointments

Comment: This situation is changing so fast it does not make sense to ask about it.  Answers will be out of date too quickly to help.

Comment: What gives you the impression anywhere is giving doses to tourists before March?

Comment: Also: What's this  tourist thing you mention?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? That's an interesting question about medical tourism.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I would actually expect a country like Russia or UAE to start offering commercial vaccination pretty soon, for serious amounts of money of course.

Comment: Well, I could tell you a few countries you could travel to to get infected. That will likely offer stronger protection than a vaccine!

Comment: I'd say getting a vaccine is not a simple *medical tourism* issue like getting an eye examination or a tooth replaced, as a vaccine works differently in every body.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt IMHO its a moot question given that the entire world is on the cusp of rolling out various vaccines, and some have even started doing so.  So by the time you organize your trip to what ever country, you could have probably sourced your vaccine locally.  In addition I think that the concept of risking your health by traveling in order to get a vaccine so that you are protected while traveling is not the most forward of thinking.

Comment: @PeterM Some areas may have stricter control of distribution order and some countries may be willing to give it to the highest bidder. Long waits for procedures are already a common cause of medical tourism. (Not advocating this, just saying that it's a question relevant to the world as exists today.)

Comment: @BernhardDöbler People travel to get their coronary bypass! Or to get procedures that aren't approved in their home countries. A vaccination is comparatively simple.

Comment: @QHarr no assumptions, please. Lets just focus on where to get vaccinated.

Comment: Note that enrolling in a trial is different from getting vaccinated. In a typical phase 3 clinical trial, you don't know in which treatment arm you will end up.

Comment: @Relaxed for the COVID vaccine trials it's very easy to know. 60% of participants get side effects that are not present with a placebo. And if you don't get side effects (or aren't sure about the ones you got), you can simply get an antibody test to confirm.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am obviously talking about knowing *beforehand*. You will eventually be informed and possibly even offered the real vaccine, even if you are in the placebo arm. That's still not a way to reliably “receive” the vaccine abroad, you're planning a trip and spending money to enter a lottery really.

Comment: @Relaxed fully agreed. But 50-66% chance of getting the vaccine is better than 0%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems possible to obtain the vaccine in the US state of Florida as a tourist:

From https://www.cbc.ca/news/business/canadian-vaccine-snowbirds-florida-covid-19-1.5863640

> Unlike many other U.S. states and Canadian provinces, Florida is offering COVID-19 vaccinations to seniors aged 65 and older during the first phase of its vaccine rollout.

> On top of that, the state is allowing non-residents — including Canadian snowbirds — to get the shot.

> "Anyone that can prove they are 65 years of age and older is eligible to receive a vaccine at no cost in Florida," the Florida Department of Health said in an email to CBC News.

Comment: Looks like you can do this in pretty much every US state now. An elderly relative of mine got vaccinated on a tourist visa. Accepting this answer as Abu Dhabi's rules are a bit unclear, but I have first-hand evidence of tourist vaccinations in the US.

Comment: This is no longer the case: Florida now requires proof of residency. http://sarasota.floridahealth.gov/newsroom/2021/01/residency.html

Comment: @lambshaanxy no proof of residency required in many other states. I.e. Washington where I live definitely doesn't require it. I can get an appointment for a 65+ year old in Seattle within 3 weeks or so, so a tourist could definitely come get their shot. But I agree - answer should be updated.

Answer (score 13):

> Where can I travel to receive a COVID vaccine as a tourist?

As far as I know, currently no country fit your 4 requirements to receive a COVID vaccine as a tourist, and no plan has been scheduled yet to do so. (mostly because governments tend to first focus on their residents, and getting enough vaccines for them is currently still a struggle + not that many countries are open to any tourist).

Regarding clinical trials, this keeps changing; you can track them on https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=COVID-19 and you most likely don't want to be in a phase 0 or 1.

Comment: But phase 3 is the "worst". You do not know if you get a real vaccine or just a vaccine for an different disease. Doctors should also not know it. This is very important to get trusted results.

Comment: @JonathanReez They can get a fever if they get a vaccine for some other disease.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi  in phases 0 or 1 you are unlikely to receive the proper doses. Higher chance in phase 3.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: in phase 0 and 1 (and possible 2) one may get different doses, 1 or two (or more times) and different interval. But these are in any case not for tourists. They must be followed for several weeks (to check antibodies, to check about complication, but also before the test for a generic medical visit)

Comment: @JonathanReez: if patient knows they get the real vaccine (phase 3), it means that the results of studies are meaningless. Phase 3 requires to have two similar groups. By knowing who received the vaccine, it changes the behaviour, and so the comparison is meaningless, and so the whole study. Researcher are hopefully smarter. BTW phase 3 requires also some follow up (so unlike to recruit tourists, it will just add costs and not results). And by CDC is deciding not to let participant to study to know if they were vaccinated for additional months (to get more useful data).c

Comment: I would be very surprised if there are no doctors with access to covid vaccines finding a cash payment from a tourist more important than to protect the local population. They might not advertise such services too broadly, but I have absolutely no doubt that they can be found if you try to look for them.

Comment: @JonathanReez People can have a "nocebo" reaction to the placebo, more likely the more they expect to have side effects from the real thing.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo anything is possible with enough cash indeed. E.g. go straight to the vaccine manufacturers, bribe some useful locals, etc.

Answer (score 12):

According to reddit, this is possible in Abu Dhabi right now with the Sinopharm vaccine.

> Sinopharm (Beijing) vaccine is now available for free in these locations
>
> I have just taken a shot, it is open 7 days a week. Expats as well. Also heard in radio, even with those with visit visa can take. Took me only 30 mins in total.
>
> Abu Dhabi:
>
> 1. Al Wathba South Majlis
> 2. Majlis Mohamed Khalaf
> 3. Majlis of first astronomer (رائد فضاء)
>
> Al Ain:
>
> 1. Majlis Al Sarooj
> 2. Majlis Al Roudha
> 3. Maljlis Al Markhaniya.
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. Two shots total, 2nd shot is after 21 days
> 2. Travelling freely back to Abu dhabi border from other emirates is possible only after 28 days from 2nd shot, once Al Hosn app shows Green status.
> 3. Aged below 12 and above 70 cannot take vaccine.
> 4. Preganant and Breast feeding mothers cannot take vaccine.
> 5. Emirates ID required for residents.
> 6. Timings typically between 9.30 am to 4 pm

from https://www.reddit.com/r/abudhabi/comments/kb0h17/sinopharm_beijing_vaccine_is_now_available_for/

Comment: but can a tourist enter Abu Dhabi?

Comment: Good question... From https://www.emirates.com/de/english/help/covid-19/dubai-travel-requirements/tourists/#82451 it seems like tourists can fly to Dubai and after a negative PCR test travel by road to Abu Dhabi, but I am not an expert at all. :)

Comment: Curious that the vaccine is available only to people below 70. Other countries like the UK have made the opposite choice to start vaccinating the elderly, instead. (I'm not claiming one strategy is better than the other though.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni probably hasn’t passed safety / efficacy checks for that age group yet.

Comment: As an aside, is safety/efficacy data (presumably from phase III trials) publicly available for this vaccine?

Comment: @dbkk "no serious safety concerns, 86% efficacy", according to https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/dec/09/chinese-covid-19-vaccine-has-86-efficacy-uae-says

Comment: Note that it would appear that you have to remain in Abu Dhabi for 49 days (21 days between the two injections, and then 28 days after the second shot)

Comment: @CSM doesn't look like you would be blocked from leaving Abu Dhabi to another country right after the 2nd shot

Answer (score 6):

There are travel packages reportedly sold to go to Russia to get th Sputnik V vaccine:

https://www.outlookindia.com/outlooktraveller/travelnews/story/70923/tourist-packages-to-ukus-and-russia-to-get-vaccinated

Hovewer, similar thing appeared earlier in Czechia and was labeled as fraud so better to be careful.

https://www.world-today-news.com/sputnik-trip-a-prague-businessman-offers-a-trip-to-russia-for-vaccinations/

-->

https://www.rbth.com/business/332938-czech-vaccine-tours-branded-as-fraud-by-russian-health-ministry

Comment: seems only available to Indian residents?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Quite possibly, I put it here as general information. Even though the title of the question is about you personally, the information here should be general.