# Can non-resident Israeli citizens get vaccinated in Israel currently?

Tags: covid-19, israel

Israel is [leading the world](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/covid-vaccine-tracker-global-distribution/) in vaccinations, with 37% of the population vaccinated as of January 23rd 2021. The Israeli PM promised that everyone in the country will be vaccinated by the end of March, thus vaccine availability is not an issue. But what about Israeli citizens who live abroad? Is it possible for them to fly to Israel and get a vaccine shot?

This could be useful for Israeli citizens who work in high-contact professions (such as nurses or pilots), but live in a country where vaccines will not be available locally [for a long time](https://asia.nikkei.com/Spotlight/Coronavirus/Japan-last-in-line-as-nations-press-ahead-with-vaccination). Related question: [Where can I travel to receive a COVID vaccine as a tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161569/where-can-i-travel-to-receive-a-covid-vaccine-as-a-tourist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to belong to an HMO aka sick fund aka קופת חולים.

If you do then you can already schedule the first shot from their app or over the phone. If you're not, I can't see how you'll get the shot. Even when the shot is not administered by the HMO, it's tied to your health records in your HMO.