# Where in the world can I travel with a COVID vaccine passport?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, event-based-effects, vaccinations

My grandparents got their vaccine shots recently and according to government authorities I should get mine by June at the latest. Where in the world can I travel with a "vaccination passport"? To clarify: I'm looking for regions where there's a distinct entry procedure for those who can prove they've been vaccinated. I.e. usually travelers have to take a PCR test, but those who are vaccinated are exempt from that rule.

Bonus questions:

1. What kind of forms/cards are accepted as a "vaccination passport"?
2. Does it matter which vaccine you've received?

This question might sound a bit far fetched at the moment, but [more than 181 million shots](https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/covid-vaccine-tracker-global-distribution/) have already been distributed around the world so this will soon become a central policy question for many countries.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161569/where-can-i-travel-to-receive-a-covid-vaccine-as-a-tourist

Comment: Doesn't seem remotely far fetched to me - we've vaccinated a quarter of our population in the UK.

Comment: @mjaggard interestingly all the current vaccination entry rules stipulate two doses of the vaccine while the UK is doing “first doses first” and only a small percentage have both doses.

Comment: @mjaggard That’s not true. Although the % of ‘fully vaccinated’ people should start to grow soon as more 2nd doses begin to fall due, the UK is currently projecting August onwards for full vaccination ie both doses for adults https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/every-adult-vaccine-august-b920049.html

Comment: Note that we do not know yet whether the vaccine also prevents you from being contagious. We only know it protects you. Until we have more data, it sounds perfectly reasonable to not lower the guard and require tests from everyone.

Comment: @spectras government policy may or may not be grounded in scientific truth. I.e. Canada won't allow Americans to enter for tourism even if they've been vaccinated and had a fresh PCR test, even though that's the gold standard for not being infectious. On the other hand Mexico allows everyone to enter with zero tests or quarantine. So there's an element of politics to it as well.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this vaccination passport as you call it is an entirely make believe thing. It is trivially easy to fake vaccination records and I wouldn't be surprised if that starts happening if some country decides to introduce such a foolish measure.

Comment: Are you only interested in the restrictions on entering the country? Remember your own country may enforce restrictions on your return home.

Comment: @thelem both but they would go into the third category of my post: Benefits apply only to local citizens/residents

Comment: `This post relates to a rapidly changing event.` That's why this is a poor type of question for StackExchange. Will the answerers promise to keep their answers up-to-date as more countries allow people with vaccine passports to enter? And in 1-2 years, it is likely the only acceptable answer to this question will be "all countries".

Comment: @pacoverflow I’m keeping my answer up to date so far :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding an answer [based on IATA's COVID](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) travel page. You can find the full text of the exemption on the IATA page, only adding the country names here for brevity.

#### Anyone in the world can go

1. Georgia. See the [official government website](https://mfa.gov.ge/MainNav/CoVID-19-sakitkhebi/sazgvris-kvetis-regulaciebi.aspx?lang=en-US) of Georgia for additional reference.
2. Guatemala
3. Lebanon
4. Moldova
5. Belize
6. Ecuador
7. Montenegro
8. El Salvador
9. Eritrea
10. Maldives
11. Bahamas
12. Antigua and Barbuda
13. Iceland. The official [Icelandic page on border control](https://www.landlaeknir.is/um-embaettid/greinar/grein/item44162/Certificate-of-vaccination-against-COVID-19-accepted-at-the-border) includes a very detailed description of what's acceptable.
14. Kosovo
15. Turks and Caicos
16. Uruguay
17. UAE
18. Jordan
19. Uganda
20. Zambia
21. [Germany](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/EN/2021/06/restrictions-for-vaccinated-travellers.html) (From June 25, 2021; Not applicable to travelers coming from [areas flagged as *areas of variant of concern* by the German RKI](https://www.rki.de/DE/Content/InfAZ/N/Neuartiges_Coronavirus/Risikogebiete_neu.html))

#### Only citizens of select countries can go

1. All EU/EEA countries - varying conditions as to what certificates are accepted but generally only EU/EEA citizens may enter using them. There are some exceptions for US and Israeli citizens and more are likely to open up soon.

#### Benefits apply only to local citizens/residents

1. Israel
2. Turkmenistan
3. Qatar
4. Serbia
5. Kuwait
6. Sri Lanka
7. Hong Kong
8. South Korea
9. Turkey
10. Samoa
11. Saudi Arabia
12. Uruguay

---

Any official vaccination certificates seem to be acceptable, as long as vaccinations from your nation are recognized by the country you are entering. I.e. [Iceland accepts](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-travel-us-to-europe-vaccine-2021-5) the US-issued CDC vaccine certificates.

Comment: Per the link above, Israel is only accepting vaccinations done in Israel, so it's not much of a travel destination.

Comment: @lambshaanxy agreed, but it does provide a travel benefit, even if only for citizens/residents. Hopefully this will eventually extend to every country in the world.

Comment: The Australian government has officially stated that they're considering the implementation of this sort of thing. https://www.smh.com.au/politics/federal/federal-government-considers-non-quarantine-options-for-vaccinated-travellers-20201229-p56qo0.html

Comment: @nick012000 I wouldn't expect to travel to Australia as a tourist sooner than 2025. They're likely to be way too spooked of COVID mutations to reopen any time soon.

Comment: @nick01200 it’s confirmed now, no tourism to Australia within the next few years: https://www.theage.com.au/politics/federal/international-borders-might-not-open-even-if-whole-country-is-vaccinated-greg-hunt-20210413-p57ixi.html

Answer (score 3):

[thepointsguy.com](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/) provides a list of countries that have a vaccination passport, as well as details for each country as to what the vaccination passport allows:

- [Cyprus](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#cyprus)
- [Estonia](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#estonia)
- [Georgia](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#georgia)
- [Iceland](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#iceland)
- [Lebanon](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#lebanon)
- [Poland](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#poland)
- [Romania](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#romania)
- [Seychelles](https://thepointsguy.com/guide/country-by-country-guide-to-where-you-can-go-if-youre-vaccinated/#seychelles)

Comment: This is pretty misleading: for example, Thailand is "planning" to relax requirements, but there's not even a date announced yet.

Comment: @lambshaanxy true but I expect the answer to be removed if I quote the entire page. I'll remove TH since the Thai authorities keep changing requirements. I think the rest is ok, with the caveats mentioned on the website.

Comment: Most of the countries on the list are planning to implement a "Green Vaccination Card" before June but the exact enforcement date was not announced yet. This holds for all EU members including Cyprus.

Comment: Ran across this from the points guy.  COVID travel restrictions by country. https://thepointsguy.com/guide/reopening-soon-a-country-by-country-guide-to-coronavirus-recovery/