# Can I convert the CDC vaccination card issued for COVID into an International Certificate of Vaccination?

Tags: usa, covid-19

As the world prepares to [reopen for vaccinated tourism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/162548/where-in-the-world-can-i-travel-with-a-covid-vaccine-passport/162550#162550), I'm facing a conundrum in regards to the paperwork required. If you get the COVID vaccine in the US these days, you will be issued a "[Vaccination Record Card](https://www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Vaccine/Pages/Prepare.aspx)" that follows the CDC-mandated format. However international travel generally requires the [International Certificate of Vaccination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ06q.jpg) - or at least that's what the requirements seem to be currently. Specifically, that's what [Iceland wants to see](https://www.landlaeknir.is/um-embaettid/greinar/grein/item44162/Certificate-of-vaccination-against-COVID-19-accepted-at-the-border) for non-EU/EEA issued vaccinations:

> Certificates from the the World Health Organization (WHO) (the International Certificate of Vaccination or the Carte Jaune/Yellow Card) is also accepted for vaccines the WHO has validated.

Is there a way to convert the CDC-issued card into the International one at the moment? Can my doctor do this for example?

Comment: In Germany a **International Certificate of Vaccination** is common place and can be bought for € 2 in most Apotheke. My doctor simply fills it out for each vaccination. Often the flu vaccination have a small sticker, which is placed in the book if you have it with you when getting the shot and stamped. [Vaccination Forms | U.S. Government Bookstore](https://bookstore.gpo.gov/catalog/vaccination-forms)

Comment: No idea why anyone would downvote this question.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Probably the modern day version of: [He's Watching You Poster | World War Era](https://worldwarera.com/products/hes-watching-you-poster). Anonymity makes it possible to make their displeasure fealt to any one who disagrees with their viewpoint.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Anonymous till the day the database leaks!

Comment: It's a little vague, but the Icelandic page linked above currently seems to suggest that the CDC cards are acceptable without further conversion. Certificates of vaccination showing an EMA-approved vaccine are accepted even if the certificates are from outside the EEA, and the CDC cards appear to conform with the requirements listed further down the page for what a vaccine certificate must include, so I would believe that these cards would be suitable for entry to Iceland, though things are very much up in the air and I wouldn't be at all certain about it.

Comment: We just returned from Iceland and they accepted the US CDC COVID Vaccination card, handwritten. We were planning on going to Malta, and they are not accepting it.

Comment: I would point out that per the [Government of Malta](https://foreignandeu.gov.mt/en/Government/Pages/COVID-19-Info.aspx) even they don't seem to accept the "International Certificate of Vaccination (the Yellow Shot Book), but rather the "EU Digital COVID Certificate" which doesn't seem to be the same, after several web searches.

Comment: @CGCampbell It really is not the same, the keyword being "Digital" in the latter. The EU Digital COVID Certificate is essentially just an entry in a national database, plus a QR code referring to it and containing a digitally signed summary (which you can either print out or load into one of many phone apps).

Comment: ahh, so I guess the point is, that it totally depends on the rules of where one wishes to travel, at the time they are doing so. The OP asks about how to get the International Certificate of Vaccination from a CDC Vaccination Card, yet if they were travelling to Malta, for instance, neither of them would work. So, we might need to look into a canonical answer for Proof of Vaccinations and countries.

Answer (score 3):

Since the yellow vaccination book (which most travellers had in the 1960's) are filled out by qualified doctors, your doctor should be able to add an entry based on the [Vaccination Record Card](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/adults/vaccination-records.html) entry.

---

In Germany a **International Certificate of Vaccination** is common place and can be bought for € 2 in most Apotheke.

This serves the same purpose as the US *Vaccination Record Card*.

My doctor simply fills it out for each vaccination.

Often the flu vaccination have a small sticker, which is placed in the book if you have it with you when getting the shot and stamped on the right hand side by the doctor (or on their behalf).

This may be true for the COVID-19 vaccine, since the image below shows 2 stickers being used.

Normally the stickers contain the brand name and a production number for each shot, so assume this image only shows what it could look like.

[image]

---

**Update** (2021-03-19):

I just received a reply from a friend in the US who ordered a CDC **International Certificate of Vaccination**,  at the given link below, on the 7th of January 2021:

> I received today, a package delivered by ups containing 25 of said yellow forms. I  guess I will take them with me tomorrow when I get my 2nd shot.
> [image]
> They filled in the vaccination history.
> [image]

---

**Sources**:

- [International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis as Approved by the World Health Organization (Package of 25) | U.S. Government Bookstore](https://bookstore.gpo.gov/products/international-certificate-vaccination-or-prophylaxis-approved-world-health-organization-0)

  - $ 24 (for 25)
- [Locating and Tracking Adult Vaccine Records | CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/adults/vaccination-records.html)
- [Corona-Impfung in Bayern: Die wichtigsten Fragen und Antworten | BR24](https://www.br.de/nachrichten/bayern/corona-impfung-in-bayern-die-wichtigsten-fragen-und-antworten,SPNIcvm)

Comment: The picture is a photoshopped symbolic picture, it doesn't show real Sars-CoV-2 vaccinations. But nonetheless, you get indeed 2 stickers, one for each dose, with the name of the vaccine and the charge number on it

Comment: @dunni Very probable. That how my flu shot stickers look like. They also contain the brand being used. Haven't gotten mine yet and didn't find a 'real' image.

Comment: 2EUR? Thieves... In California Kaiser (one of the largest HMOs here) printed the yellow booklet for me when I asked for it, on the spot, with all my vaccines listed in it. For free.