# Am I allowed to glue my vaccine card to my passport?

Tags: passports

I got vaccinated and I want to attach my vaccination card to my passport. I figure that I can staple or glue it onto one of the pages reserved for visas. I wonder if that counts as modifying it or has unforeseen negative consequences. I have a US passport.

Comment: Do NOT glue till you have a clear answer. Stapling is less likely a problem, but I do know the details of what is allowed.

Comment: That makes sense to me. I could see a case that it could make it look like it's hiding travel details. At least with a staple, someone could take it out if they wanted to

Comment: I'd get it laminated and carry it separately. Its likely you'll need it for domestic purposes too in the next few months.

Comment: Paperclips seem like a simple and safe solution.

Comment: (In the past) I have secured a folded vaccination certificate with an elastic band inside the passport.

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to disfigure your passport, this includes but is not limited to doodling, taking notes, maintaining your grocery list on empty pages. Different countries have different requirements and some may flat out refuse to accept a tampered passport.

Comment: In addition, how are you going to move your vaccination card to a new passport?

Comment: Does it not have information on both sides? Also it's a bit early to know how long it will be valid.

Comment: There is no garantie that the US specific **vaccination card** (whether glued in or not) will be recognized in other countries. This is what a **International Certificate of Vaccination** is intended for. See related question: [Can I convert the CDC vaccination card issued for COVID into an International Certificate of Vaccination?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162588/95267)

Comment: @JonathanReez Don't laminate--there might be booster shots to add later.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I and many others have been specifically told to get the Covid-19 card laminated by the medical personnel administering the vaccine. Who has told you that the government wants to record booster shots on the card? Nobody has. Why give contradictory guidance that confuses others?

Comment: @Zorkolot [2021-04-21: What You Need to Know About Your Covid-19 Vaccine Card - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/article/covid-vaccine-card.html) *Laminating your card will make it more durable if you’re planning to carry it around in your wallet, though there has been some concern about lamination because **it would prevent information from future booster shots from being added.***

Comment: @MarkJohnson there's no official guidance on that. This is repeating the same assumption earlier that it might be. We are free to do whatever we want with the card, including laminate it. To go further- "Might be" is not in the same realm as "required" or "the law" or "regulation". You can't be arrested for it "might be".

Comment: @Zorkolot That is the point. CDC (who designed the card) make no meantion that it **should** be laminated after the 2nd shot. They don't even meantion how the the 2 'Other' entries should be used. [Getting Your COVID-19 Vaccine | CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/expect.html). **Common sense** should, however, tell you that they were not deliberately added **never** to be used. In the **International Certificate of Vaccination** books, the 'Other' fields are presently being used for the COVID-19 shots (at least that where mine has been entered).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Your own argument defeats itself because the CDC didn't issue the cards in the first place. The U.S. government did. The CDC does not tell us what to do. If lamination was an issue it would have been addressed by now, not months later. You realize this insistence on saying "don't do it just in case" is not convincing?

Comment: @Zorkolot I didn't state that the CDC issued the card, I stated that they **designed** it. Why else do you think that the **CDC Logo** has been placed in the upper right hand corner? The only thing that is convincing, is that you are not applying **common sense** in this matter.

Comment: @Zorkolot The CDC (cdc.gov) is a government agency [Centers for Disease Control and Prevention](https://www.cdc.gov/). Their recommendation is to photograph the card.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That's nice. We are free to state facts. I have not said anything untrue or false in this thread. No official agency, including the CDC has advised that booster shots will be further recorded on the card. Insinuating otherwise is jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @Zorkolot True, but none of your **opinions** has helped to answer the OP question. The main purpose of a **Vaccine Card** is to register vaccination (independent of what any medical personnel administering may say to the contrary). Statements stating the **true purpose** does not bring confusion (as you claimed to LorenPechtel) but clarity.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Then I guess you need to contact an admin then since you started the rambling discussion. You apparently have an issue with the facts I've presented.

Comment: @Zorkolot I have no issue with `the facts I've presented`. I consider them completely irrelevant to the topic of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bad idea, for at least two reasons.  First, if a US government officer determines that the vaccine card constitutes an "unauthorized change, obliteration, entry or photograph" within the meaning of [22 CFR 51.4(g)(5)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/51.4#g_5), the officer could "either take possession of the passport or sends a written notice" to you rendering the passport invalid.

Second, any other country's laws might require its immigration inspectors to refuse to recognize the passport even if the US government holds that the passport is still valid.  The last thing you want is trouble traveling to another country because of your vaccination card.

A better approach: use a paperclip, as suggested in the comments, or get a travel wallet to keep both documents.  You might also consider a sleeve with a pocket, an envelope, or even a small booklet that you could glue the card into without invalidating the passport, that you could strap to the passport with a rubber band.

Now I realize I haven't actually made a definitive statement about whether gluing the card to the passport is allowed.  But the potential consequences of doing it are sufficiently severe, and the likelihood sufficiently low that it is allowed (and that every government officer you meet will agree that it is allowed) that the best course of action is just to assume that it's fobidden.

Comment: Of note: US officials are at least occasionally strict about this sort of thing. A friend of mine was once denied a US visa because he had a [Soviet Unterzoegersdorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_Unterzoegersdorf) stamp in his passport. A pasted-in vaccination card is obviously more noticeable than a stamp from a fictional country, though it is never certain just how grumpy any individual officer is likely to get about it. I agree that the risks outweigh the benefits here.

Comment: @mlc but a stamp from a fictitious country is arguably fraudulent, while a true vaccination card is not.  I mention this because the US passport itself suggests that unauthorized modification could be a crime, but the statute defining the crime uses the word "falsely."  The stamp your friend had is false; the card is not (which is why I didn't mention the criminal code in this answer).  I'm not certain that distinction is relevant, but it might be.

Comment: It's not a crime afaik under US law to modify a _non-US_ passport, as in my friend's case. (It may or may not be a crime under the laws of their country of citizenship; I have no idea.) It ended up working out okay, as they were able to get a replacement passport and get the US visa put into that replacement, which makes me think the US was viewing the passport as damaged rather than fraudulent, but, again, avoiding being in a situation where you must discuss any of this with any official seems like the way to go here, especially when the solution is as simple as a paper clip.

Comment: @mlc the relevant statute, [18 USC 1543](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1543), is not restricted to US passports.  I would not expect the US to tolerate fraud perpetrated with a falsified foreign passport, would you?  This of course underscores that the crime is the deception rather than the modification _per se._

Answer (score -1):

If you get the COVID vaccine in the US these days, you will be issued a "[Vaccination Record Card](https://www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Vaccine/Pages/Prepare.aspx)" that follows the CDC-mandated format. However international travel would most likely require the [International Certificate of Vaccination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZ06q.jpg) - or at least that's what the requirements seem to be currently. Specifically, that's what [Iceland wants to see](https://www.landlaeknir.is/um-embaettid/greinar/grein/item44162/Certificate-of-vaccination-against-COVID-19-accepted-at-the-border) for non-EU/EEA issued vaccinations:

> Certificates from the the World Health Organization (WHO) (the International Certificate of Vaccination or the Carte Jaune/Yellow Card) is also accepted for vaccines the WHO has validated.

Of course these requirements are in a constant state of flux and I won’t be surprised if the CDC certificate will eventually be accepted everywhere but I’d err on the side of caution and get the international version instead. So when you go get your vaccination, fill out the International certificate with your details (a blank version can be purchased on Amazon) and then ask the vaccination workers to stamp it in addition to the CDC paper. If that doesn’t work or you’ve already done your shot, you can always ask your doctor to do it instead.

Afterwards, travel with your passport and your international vaccine certificate. You might still need the CDC card for domestic purposes so I’d keep it safe too but you’re unlikely to need it for international trips.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @phoog I’m trying to explain why OP has the wrong solution to the underlying problem that they’re trying to solve.