# Alles gurgelt! for tourists in Vienna

Tags: covid-19, vienna

[Alles gurgelt!](https://allesgurgelt.at/en/) is a COVID testing scheme in Vienna. One takes a gargle PCR test at home, drops off the kit at various locations and receives an answer within 24 hours.

I am not Austrian or an EU member and may visit Vienna as a tourist. I am vaccinated for COVID, but I still need to take a PCR test. Could I take an Alles gurgelt test? [This](https://www.wien.info/en/travel-info/corona-information/testing-options-vienna-guests-388220) page seems to imply the answer is "yes", but their website says participation is open to "all people who live or work in Vienna", which doesn't seem to include tourists.

If I can take the test, is it possible to get the resuts in English? And will the report contain my (foreign) passport number? A report in German or one without my passport number is not useful to me.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What proof of vaccination to you have? An entry in your **International Certificate of Vaccination** book should be sufficient (and considered equivalent) for the test presently required to visit Restaurants or other public places.

Comment: Someone has marked this as spam, which gives an automated downvote. I feel the question is not a spam question.

Comment: [Alles gurgelt! | Wir statt Virus!](https://allesgurgelt.at/en/) (in English) states *The lab report is issued in multiple languages to facilitate e.g. border crossing.*

Comment: I surely don't hope that these tests are accepted for travelling even if the provider claims so in their FAQs. With a self test, there is neither a verification that the correct person has been tested, that the test sample has been obtained correctly, nor when the sample has been obtained (which is relevant since most time limits start when the test was taken and not when the test result was completed).

Comment: Not a downvoter, but in central Europe many people have not started travelling as a Tourist, as they don't consider the pandemic being over.

Comment: I suggest you read up on the differences between PCR-tests (which are processed in a lab and done by medical personnel) and self-/quick-tests (which can be done by anyone and are far less reliable).

Comment: @Erik This provider actually offers a PCR-test, which is done by yourself and then delivered to a laboratory for analysis.

Comment: This is actually a *PCR **gargle** test*, which may be different to a standard PCR test.

Comment: @MarkJohnson PCR refers to how the test is analyzed and not how the sample is taken (with a swab or as here by gargling a saline solution).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, I know. The *PCR gargle test* result is analysed in a Labor as with a PCR-Test. This type of test is widly used in Austria (where it was developed) because it doesn't require medical personal to take the sample. [2020-08-22: Neuer Corona-Test: gurgeln, spucken, analysieren | BR24](https://www.br.de/nachrichten/deutschland-welt/neuer-corona-test-gurgeln-spucken-analysieren,S8Eiun4). Your consern about the 'self' (do it home) tests is, however, completely justified.

Comment: When you take the test “with authentication” you have to provide an image of your identity card or passport and video yourself taking the test. This is the only way to get a signed certificate, which will have your ID number on it. You’re supposed to show this (or proof of vaccination) in restaurants, etc but it’s not carefully policed. I’m afraid I don’t know if it’s valid for travel.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The OP may need the test to travel outside of Austria (otherwise they wouldn't care about it being in English), including returning to their country of residence. Austrian rules around vaccinations and public places are completely irrelevant, as is the German practice of using the International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis for Covid vaccination.

Comment: @Relaxed Your notion that the WTO ICVP (or that it is a soly German practice) is irrelevant is not correct. [Vaccination requirements for international travel - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccination_requirements_for_international_travel): *At border checks, these travellers are required to show proof of vaccination against specific diseases; the most widely used vaccination record is the [International Certificate of Vaccination or Prophylaxis (ICVP or Carte Jaune/Yellow Card)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Certificate_of_Vaccination_or_Prophylaxis)*.

Comment: I am fully aware of what the ICVP is and never implied it was a German thing. It's obviously quite common, especially for yellow fever vaccination. My comment is about its use *for Covid-19 vaccinations* and the text you quote doesn't even address that specifically. So why bother with an irrelevant link? In reality, Germany is not the only country to do it but it is far from universal and the ICVP has been displaced by various regional or national digital certificates. You shouldn't and cannot assume the OP has one. Stop dumping irrelevant quotes and address the points that are being made.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Incidentally, you want to lecture me on the ICVP but you hadn't used its full name until I wrote it in my comment and you mixed up your international organisations, it's the WHO, not the WTO.

Comment: @Relaxed I used for the first time here on the 21st of February 2021: [usa - Can I convert the CDC vaccination card issued for COVID into an International Certificate of Vaccination? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/162596/95267).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Used what? The incomplete name? Glad to know that.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to register without stating that I work or live in Vienna.

After registering you will receive a QR code that can be used to pick up the test kits at any of the pickup/drop off locations like Billa or Bipa.

The results are in both English and German. Included in the results there is a document/ID number that I believe can be your passport number.

To take the at-home test you can use the same login that you used to register or sign in as a guest. This means that if someone else registers and picks up a test, you should be able to use it for yourself with all your own personal details (if for some reason you were not able to register).

Hope that helps